# Dont want sex with husband

Tags: nikah, sin

I just married actually I don't want to marry and want to study bcz of family issues I have to do.. Now I'm still studying but I don't want any sex relation with my husband atleast for 1 and half year and he is agreed that he don't have issue I can continue my study. But people say if married couple don't do sex relation with husband within 3 months.. Their nikah will drop

Comment: Plz guys must answer to my Question

Comment: @Ishue having intimate relations will not hinder or ruin your studies. This is a false assumption. There is **no** problem in having relations and continuing your studies.

Comment: Yes that is true. But it applies only to the women because it is they who need it (the sex) most. Abu Bakr ordered the sahaba to return to their wives whenever their journey continued for more than 3 months. Upon your denial from having sex, your husband may always respond by having a need to marry a second woman of his choice. It does not break your wedlock if you, being the woman, do not want to have sex. It is the case where a couple may agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

salam sister
get in touch with local masjid but if your husband has agreed to this can't see a problem
(this is my opnion get in touch with local masjid to find out what the holy prophet saw and allah says)
hope it all works out for you sister take care